# In Node v.0.12, will there be any method to iterate over Map()?

Tags: node.js, dictionary, ecmascript-harmony

If you create a Map() is there any method whatsoever to iterate over it? I know Node 0.12 isn't out yet, but 0.11.x is well on it's way and I can't figure it out in the devel branch,

```
var m = new Map();
m.set('foo', 'bar');
```

Without knowing 'foo', is there anyway to discover that the key has been set? Is there a `.keys()` or anything on any object that will permit this or are we out of luck until v8 picks up more of ES6, and consequently the release of Node 0.14.

Answer (score 0):

Both Node.js 0.12 and iojs (since its initial release) implement iteration over Map and Set instances. With `Map` instances For example:

```
for (let entry of map) {
    // Do something with entry, which looks like [key, val]
}
```

or

```
map.forEach(function (val, key) {
    // Do something with key and val.
});
```

If you want to iterate over just the keys or just the values, then there are helper methods that return iterators called `keys` and `values` to do this.

Comment: I assume this was accurate a few weeks ago, but an update is in order now that Node 0.12 is out. Even without the --harmony flag, Map.prototype.keys, Map.prototype.values, and Map.prototype.forEach are all implemented (same for Set, though note .keys() and .values() are synonymous in that case).